# Javascript calling function from within function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
function newsort(array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        alert(array);
    } else {
        mid = array.length / 2;
        left = [];
        right = [];
        for (i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            left.push(array[i]);
        }
        for (i = mid; i <= array.length; i++) {
            right.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    result = merge(left, right);
    alert(result);
};

function merge(left, right) {
    alert(left);
}

function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr3 = [];
    while (arr1.length > 0 && arr2.length > 0) {
        if (arr1[0] <= arr2[0]) {
            arr3.push(arr1.shift());
        } else {
            arr3.push(arr2.shift());
        }
    }

    while (arr1.length > 0) {
        arr3.push(arr1.shift());
    }

    while (arr2.length > 0) {
        arr3.push(arr2.shift());
    }
    //  time = timeSortingAlgorithm(arr3, newsort(array));
    //  return time;
    return arr3;
};

function makeRandomArray(size) {
    var result = Array();
    while (size > 0) {
        result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000));
        --size;
    }
    return result;
}

function timeSortingAlgorithm(array, sortingAlgorithm) {
    var startTime = new Date();
    newsort(array);
    var endTime = new Date();
    return endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
}

var array = makeRandomArray(6);
newsort(array);
//timeSortingAlgorithm(array,newsort);
```

When I run this code, the idea is that it will take the function merge and send the two halves of the array to newsort - which then merges them together, sorted. The array is created by the makeRandomArray function. However, I cannot figure out how to incorporate the timeSortingAlgorithm(array, sortingAlgorithm) function, as when I call it - nothing happens. I have the calls commented out at the moment, but when I take those out - no output at all. If I leave that function out of the process altogether - everything works fine.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no, but i am using aptana......so there is that.

Comment: aptana !== browser console

Comment: Is this supposed to be merge-sort? Because its supposed to be recursive, which this is not...

Answer (score 1):

Three is a major problem with your implementation.

1. If you are trying to implement Merge Sort, the array has to be split and the split parts have to be sorted before merging.

Apart from that, the problems which I could find are

1. You are using global variables, `mid`, `left` and `right` are global variables.
2. You don't return the sorted arrays back from `newsort` function.
3. You have two merge functions defined.
4. Your `mid` should be an integer, as you are using that for indexing an array and that will return `undefined` for floating point numbers.

So, the fixed implementation looks like this

```
function newsort(array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return array;
    } else {
        var mid   = parseInt(array.length / 2), left  = [], right = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            left.push(array[i]);
        }
        for (i = mid; i < array.length; i++) {
            right.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return merge(newsort(left), newsort(right));
};

function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr3 = [];
    while (arr1.length > 0 && arr2.length > 0) {
        if (arr1[0] <= arr2[0]) {
            arr3.push(arr1.shift());
        } else {
            arr3.push(arr2.shift());
        }
    }

    while (arr1.length > 0) {
        arr3.push(arr1.shift());
    }

    while (arr2.length > 0) {
        arr3.push(arr2.shift());
    }
    return arr3;
};

function timeSortingAlgorithm(array, sortingAlgorithm) {
    var startTime = new Date(), result = sortingAlgorithm(array);
    console.log(new Date().getMilliseconds() - startTime.getMilliseconds());
    return result;
}

var array = makeRandomArray(6);
console.log(array);
console.log(timeSortingAlgorithm(array, newsort));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an infinite loop.

when you run this line :

```
time = timeSortingAlgorithm(arr3, newsort(array));
```

You call `newsort`.

`newsort` call the function `merge` which then run over, guess what, this line :

```
time = timeSortingAlgorithm(arr3, newsort(array));
```